# e2e-tests "We should find a port before the reader ends"

Tags: ink, smart-contract, cargo-contract

I am doing a basic `E2E test using` the [flipper example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/flipper/lib.rs).

This is my contract version

[image]

I have install the [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node)

I am running with the "nightly-2023-02-09" (cargo +nightly-2023-02-09 test --features e2e-tests)

**Does anyone knows why this happens ?**

```rs
---- flipper::e2e_tests::it_works stdout ----
thread 'flipper::e2e_tests::it_works' panicked at 'We should find a port before the reader ends', /home/silveira/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_e2e-4.2.1/src/node_proc.rs:192:10
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

[image]

Cargo.toml

```rs
[package]
name = "flipper"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>"]
edition = "2021"
publish = false

[dependencies]
ink = { version = "4.2.1", default-features = false }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.6.3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.5", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }

[dev-dependencies]
ink_e2e = { version = "4.2.1" }

[lib]
path = "src/lib.rs"

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
]
ink-as-dependency = []
e2e-tests = []
```

Comment: Note : this is a question. i have this configuration ```Rust > = 1.70 + pallet-contracts >= polkadot-1.0.0 = cargo-contract 4.0.0-alpha``` but i still have the same error

Comment: Hi, the e2e test does not work after the 3.1.0 has been yanked for either versions of it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like cargo-contract 3.1.0 has been [yanked](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/1239#issuecomment-1653683340).

cargo-contract compatibility with different rust toolchains:

- Rust <= 1.69 + pallet-contracts < polkadot-1.0.0 = cargo-contract
  3.0.1
- Rust > = 1.70 + pallet-contracts >= polkadot-1.0.0 = cargo-contract 4.0.0-alpha

The e2e test does not work after the 3.1.0 has been yanked for either versions of it.

A new version cargo-contract 3.2.0 was release but the error remains([Issue](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/1259)).

---

### Update Update Update Update Update Update Update Update

**This was sorted with the ink version 4.3.**

cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "flipper"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>"]
edition = "2021"
publish = false

[dependencies]
ink = { version = "4.3.0", default-features = false }
scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.5", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }

[dev-dependencies]
ink_e2e = { version = "4.3.0" }

[lib]
path = "src/lib.rs"

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = ["ink/std", "scale/std", "scale-info/std"]
ink-as-dependency = []
e2e-tests = []
```