# e2e-tests We should find port before reader ends - ink! 4.2.1, rust 1.69, cargo contracts 3.0.1

Tags: ink, testing

I have the same problem and error message as described here: [e2e-tests "We should find a port before the reader ends"](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9512/e2e-tests-we-should-find-a-port-before-the-reader-ends) for rust = 1.69 and cargo-contract-contract 3.0.1-unknown-x86_64-apple-darwin. I tried everything that came to mind with downgrading, upgrading, etc. Problem persists. Solutions from the provided link don't work.

```
ink_e2e = 4.2.1
substrate-contracts-node = 0.29 or 0.30 both checked
```

It happens when I try to run e2e with `cargo test --features e2e-tests` 
with output:

```
    e2e_tests::e2e_minting_works stdout ----
thread 'magink::e2e_tests::e2e_minting_works' panicked at 'We should find a port before the reader ends', /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_e2e-4.2.1/src/node_proc.rs:192:10
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/std/src/panicking.rs:579:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/panicking.rs:64:14
   2: core::panicking::panic_display
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/panicking.rs:147:5
   3: core::panicking::panic_str
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/panicking.rs:131:5
   4: core::option::expect_failed
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/option.rs:2045:5
   5: core::option::Option<T>::expect
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/option.rs:905:21
   6: ink_e2e::node_proc::find_substrate_port_from_output
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_e2e-4.2.1/src/node_proc.rs:166:5
   7: ink_e2e::node_proc::TestNodeProcessBuilder<R>::spawn::{{closure}}
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_e2e-4.2.1/src/node_proc.rs:138:23
   8: magink::magink::e2e_tests::e2e_minting_works::{{closure}}
             at ./lib.rs:281:9
   9: <core::pin::Pin<P> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/future/future.rs:125:9
  10: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CoreGuard::block_on::{{closure}}::{{closure}}::{{closure}}
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/scheduler/current_thread/mod.rs:665:57
  11: tokio::runtime::coop::with_budget
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/coop.rs:107:5
  12: tokio::runtime::coop::budget
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/coop.rs:73:5
  13: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CoreGuard::block_on::{{closure}}::{{closure}}
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/scheduler/current_thread/mod.rs:665:25
  14: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::Context::enter
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/scheduler/current_thread/mod.rs:410:19
  15: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CoreGuard::block_on::{{closure}}
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/scheduler/current_thread/mod.rs:664:36
  16: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CoreGuard::enter::{{closure}}
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/scheduler/current_thread/mod.rs:743:68
  17: tokio::runtime::context::scoped::Scoped<T>::set
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/context/scoped.rs:40:9
  18: tokio::runtime::context::set_scheduler::{{closure}}
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/context.rs:176:26
  19: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::try_with
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/std/src/thread/local.rs:446:16
  20: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::with
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/std/src/thread/local.rs:422:9
  21: tokio::runtime::context::set_scheduler
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/context.rs:176:9
  22: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CoreGuard::enter
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/scheduler/current_thread/mod.rs:743:27
  23: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CoreGuard::block_on
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/scheduler/current_thread/mod.rs:652:19
  24: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CurrentThread::block_on::{{closure}}
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/scheduler/current_thread/mod.rs:175:28
  25: tokio::runtime::context::runtime::enter_runtime
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/context/runtime.rs:65:16
  26: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CurrentThread::block_on
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/scheduler/current_thread/mod.rs:167:9
  27: tokio::runtime::runtime::Runtime::block_on
             at /Users/{userName}/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.31.0/src/runtime/runtime.rs:347:47
  28: magink::magink::e2e_tests::e2e_minting_works
             at ./lib.rs:281:9
  29: magink::magink::e2e_tests::e2e_minting_works::{{closure}}
             at ./lib.rs:282:74
  30: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
  31: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.


failures:
    magink::e2e_tests::e2e_minting_works

test result: FAILED. 3 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.09s
```

Can someone advise?